# Should my UK visa sponsor mention details of my other sibling who stays with us for my application?

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, visa-sponsors

I will be requesting my mother for providing me financial assistance for any additional expenses I may incur on my trip to the UK. She has been regularly paying me an allowance which is in addition to my income.
My mother is retired but she is not dependent on me or my sister for financial assistance. Should it be important to mention details about my sister AND give documentation about my sister’s job and income too?
This application is only for my travel from India to the UK. My sister and mother would not be accompanying me.

Thank you

Comment: If your sister is not dependent on you, or not paying any amount for your trip, no need to mention it.

Comment: Note that relying on your retired mother's money to go to UK (as a tourist) mostly means that your financials are not strong enough. It makes you more likely to illegally immigrate to UK (according to visa officers) and can likely result in refusal. Assess yourself if your financials are strong enough.

Comment: @AnishSheela sorry for not mentioning my details. I am a resident doctor at a prestigious oncological centre in Mumbai. I have enough money to travel, but I have been given money by my mother on a regular basis needs explanation and also my money is just a little more than covering my 4 day trip for a conference visit to the UK in May 23. I also have my university exam of MD on June 1 2023. I have a U.S. visa obtained from my mothers sponsorship when she was retired. So I want to show that my mother is financially strong and doesn’t depend on my/ my sisters money nor has dependents

Comment: You can just add that as an income source - allowance from parent. May be attach a bank statement of your mother, if the money is significant.

Comment: If this is for a conference, is there a reason this is not paid by your institution? Unless this is a job market, in many fields it’s unusual to pay for conferences out of one’s pocket (or mother’s pocket).

Comment: @jcaron yes I am presenting two case reports. So our institute pays for thesis (research) and only once. So I am paying out of my pocket for enhancing my knowledge from the meeting and meeting the doyens of my field from prestigious centres like Guy’s and St Thomas and GOSH, at the conference. Also my stipend arrives on 8th every month. With my stipend in my pocket I shall have £ 2100 which are enough for my trip. Should I mention this on my covering letter about my prospective £ 700 on it’s way before my trip  

Answer (score 2):

You may be approaching this the wrong way. Needing a sponsor is a weakness for a UK visa application. So if financing your trip yourself is feasible and makes sense, it would be better to not have your mother listed as a sponsor.

The allowance you get from your mother has to be mentioned, as unexplained income is very bad for a UK visa application. A parent regularly sending their adult children money isn't that unusual, so I wouldn't expect that you need much of a justification here.

Your sister seems to be entirely unrelated to your trip, so she shouldn't really show up in your application.

Comment: Thank you. I have mentioned on my application that while I may be able to sustain myself with my own savings, my mom will be contributing to some funds for any unanticipated or additional expenses I may incur on my trip. I have an estimated expenditure of 1225 GBP for the trip and have savings of 1475 GBP. I hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

From your post and comments, these are the facts.

1. You have a stable job and regular income.
2. You want to go to UK to attend a conference (Assuming you gets an invitation letter from organizers).
3. You have compelling reason to return back to India. (MD exam)
4. You are receiving some kind of allowance from your mom.
5. You already have a US visa.

All these are positive things and you don't have to worry. As Arno said in another answer, if you can afford the trip by yourself, without undue financial stress, don't depend on your mother. Just apply as yourself, as its credible. There shouldn't be much variation in expenses for 4 day trip.

Regarding your allowance, you can attach the bank statements from your mother to prove that that amount is legally obtained (use the same account on which she is transferring the amount) and may be a letter from your mom stating the same.

If you still want to list your mother as sponsor, fill the form accordingly, get a letter from your mother, along with her bank statements, stating that she is willing to sponsor for additional expenses. That will be enough. Follow the document checklist you obtained, after submitting your application.

Comment: yes I have an invitation from the organiser. Thank you for your inputs. My mom will be kind of a go to person like a guarantor for this trip where she may pay me if I need the money. Mostly I won’t need her money. 